# Mura 6 - Japanese characters are saved as question marks

Tags: coldfusion, mura

I have Mura 6 installed.

Japanese character are not saving from Mura admin on new page creation/updation.

I have changed the `tcontent` table from `text` to `nvarchar` and tried to do an insert query from SSMS with Japanese text and it does save the text as Japanese now.

```
update tcontent set body = N'japanese-text' where id = 123;
```

I can't find the insert/update query file where i need to put prefix N to save as `nvarchar`.

Where I need to change the query on Mura code or how can I get it to accept non-latin characters?

**Note:** Instead of making text to nvarchar, use nText. By default mura should set them as ntext anyway when mura db is initialised and created during setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unicode generally works with Coldfusion, so the first thing to check is if you have set up your database connection properly.

[This forum post](http://www.getmura.com/forum/messages.cfm?threadid=4BE15F5A-5CCB-4F69-8DCCF6759711C2B3) suggests

> Double check to make sure that your datasource is set to use unicode.

and

> For sql server makes sure that you have check the "String Format" checkbox under your datasource's advanced settings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked the String Format and it still saves the text as ????? do i need to restart server or reload application?

Comment: Couldn't hurt to try that.

Comment: Yeahhhhhh. great. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If you changed the table from `TEXT` to `NVARCHAR`, make sure you chose `NVARCHAR(MAX)` as the datatype.

Comment: Of course i did, but thats a good reminder. Have a great day Tomalak - Vielen Dank ^_^